# Python testwrap.wrap replacing whitespace dispite disable

Tags: python, word-wrap

```
>>> string
'This contain slashN:\n'
>>> textwrap.wrap(string, 40)
['This contain slashN:']
>>> textwrap.wrap(string, 40, replace_whitespace=False)
['This contain slashN:']
>>>
```

I expected
`['This contain slashN:\n']`
Why is `textwrap.wrap` still replacing whitespace (`\n` here)?
While its [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.TextWrapper.replace_whitespace) says:

> replace_whitespace
>
> (default: True) If true, after tab expansion but before wrapping, the wrap() method will replace each whitespace character with a single space. The whitespace characters replaced are as follows: tab, newline, vertical tab, formfeed, and carriage return ('\t\n\v\f\r').
>
> Note
>
> If expand_tabs is false and replace_whitespace is true, each tab character will be replaced by a single space, which is not the same as tab expansion.
>
> Note
>
> If replace_whitespace is false, newlines may appear in the middle of a line and cause strange output. For this reason, text should be split into paragraphs (using str.splitlines() or similar) which are wrapped separately.

EDIT: To add what I expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a separate argument `drop_whitespace` for stripping leading and trailing whitespace.  It defaults to true.  Pass False to turn that off:

```
>>> textwrap.wrap('This contain slashN:\n', 40, replace_whitespace=False, drop_whitespace=False)
['This contain slashN:\n']
```

Comment: but why `replace_whitespace=False` not retaining `\n`?

Comment: @user2763554: *Because there is a different argument for stripping leading and trailing whitespace*.  The documentation for every argument doesn't describe everything the entire function does; the fact there is an argument that says it's for deciding whether leading/trailing whitespace is stripped means that by default leading/trailing whitespace is stripped .  Also, you can see that `replace_whitespace` is not applying here, because your `\n` is not *replaced* by a space, it's just removed entirely.